# Firebase / FCM Push Messages - topics and tokens cleanup

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push messages for a really big amount of users. I guess that topics is a pretty good fit for this scenario. Anyway, there are a few questions I cannot still resolve:

How can I know which topics are invalid / expired when sending a push message to a topic? (think on more than 1M of tokens related)

Is there a way for getting the amount of relations for a topic? I could keep the tokens on DB and make this aggregation by myself, but I'm wondering if there is any other option by using any method of the public API

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I know which topics are invalid / expired when sending a push message to a topic? (think on more than 1M of tokens related)*

There is currently no way to check if a topic is invalid/expired. A topic doesn't even auto-invalidate/expire. A topic ceases to exist if there are no more subscribers to it, but sending a message to a topic (a valid topic name), regardless if there is a subscriber or not would **not** return an error that lets you know if it doesn't exist.

> *Is there a way for getting the amount of relations for a topic?*

There is currently no API that handles this. It is the developer's responsibility to keep track of this data (in your case, the number of subscribed) when they need it.

Comment: Thanks @AL.! do you know what may happen when pushing to topics with many invalid tokens? I know AWS SNS keeps track of invalid push messages and they may ban your account in case when exceeding a limit. I haven't found anything about it on Firebase doc.

Comment: You'd still receive a success response and valid tokens would still receive a push notification. Using topics has no limits when it comes to the subscribers count.